# WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support. What is this message?

Tags: docker, grep, system-paths

When trying to find the path for the Docker folder on the PC, I used the following code.  This code uses grep to narrow and specify exactly what I wanted to find - specifically I wanted to find the Docker root directory.

```
docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir"
```

I received the following:

```
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

I was concerned that this information was coming from some kind of Docker error or issue in my Docker settings.  I then tried using the more generic docker command:

```
docker info
```

This docker command returned much more information than I needed. But buried within the large quantity of information docker returned was the root path of the Docker directory (shown below).  And this Docker command also returned those same Docker warnings messages.

```
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

So after doing a good bit of searching, I determined that this Docker "Warning" is nothing important.  And this warning is really just an unnecessary warning. It turns out the "blkio"  is related to Docker and file mounting on the host PC.  Below is a link to the Docker website with information about the "blkio" subsys:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt

Answer (score 24):

```
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device
```

This warning is not an error.  And for most users, this warning can be ignored.  This "blkio" is a Docker subsystem used in larger Docker production environments.

I am placing this post with both the question and the answer because this information was not readily available at Stack overflow or elsewhere.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt